# ¿Como pasar de getBinaryStream a formato imagen?

Tags: java, mysql, imagen, binario

Estoy intentando sacar unas imágenes que metí en la base de datos (phpmyadmin) así:
`pst.setBinaryStream(12, FIPI);`
El caso es que ahora quiero sacar esa misma imagen, cosa que estoy haciendo así:
`fperfil = (result.getBinaryStream(12));`
El problema es que no sé como pasar eso a imagen para que salga en un JLabel.

Answer (score 2):

Lo conseguí así:

```java
try {
    byte[] data = ffondo.readAllBytes();
    BufferedImage img;
    img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
    ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(img);

    JLabel la = new JLabel(icono);
    la.setBounds(200, 15, 340, 208);
    panel.add(la);

} catch (IOException ioException) {
    ioException.printStackTrace();
}
```